# Pandas Data Frame sum floating values

Tags: python, pandas

So i'm somewhat new to python. I am nearly done with a project I am working on where I needed to map the distance between two longitude and latitude points. There is a competitive index that we are creating based on this distance, which always results in some decimal value or 0. In turn I have all these values stored in a pandas dataframe, and am attempting to sum them all together to create some total of these indexes.

Here is my code. (For ths sake of brevity I did not list all c1 to c435 in line 6)

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df_distance = pd.DataFrame(['C1': 'C413'])])

df4 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Jake\PycharmProjects\FM-NAICS-1.0\DF4.csv')
with open("dist_test.csv", "w") as csvfile:
csize = 10 ** 5
for df3 in pd.read_csv(r'DF3.csv', keep_default_na=False, chunksize=csize):
    for index, row in df3.iterrows():
        lat1 = row['Lat']
        lon1 = row['Long']
        distance = 0
        for index2,row2 in df4.iterrows():
            lat2 = row2['Lat']
            lon2 = row2['Long']
            coords_1 = [lat1, lon1]
            coords_2 = [lat2, lon2]
            distance = geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).miles
            if distance > 300:
                distance = 0
            else:
                distance = distance
            df_distance = pd.DataFrame([distance])
            distance_index = ((300 - distance)/300)
            if distance_index != 1:
                distance_index = distance_index
            else:
                distance_index = None
            di_df = pd.DataFrame([distance_index])
            sum_di = di_df.sum()
        exit()
```

How can I get my sum_di to sum all values that are in the data frame distance index? right now I am simply getting the output of each point and its dtype: float 64.

I will want to append this to the end of the di_df data frame.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you guys so much.

Comment: that's because you are summing it inside of the loop, sum it outside

Comment: You are re-instantiating `df_distance` and `di_df` in every loop of df4. I 'm not sure i fully understand your intentions, but I think that might be an issue.

Comment: @arjun I am using the sum because I want a sum of distance indexes for each set of 400 distances that are used in the distance index. Some will come back with values and some won't, im attempting to sum them all to get a total and append that onto the di_df data frame so that it has each individual distance, as well as the others.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to specify the column:

```
>>> sum_di = di_df['distance_index'].sum()
```

Also, be sure it's happening outside the loop, rather than inside, if you intend to sum once you're finished.

Comment: This gives me an error on 
 inline 'TypeError: an integer is required'